# d365 opt-out from auto numbering

Tags: dynamics-crm

My customer wants to go back to manual numbering of work orders in D365 Field Service. I cannot find any option to opt-out from this. Any ideas how to make it easier without the need to set up environment from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is explicitly stated that you cannot go back once you opt-in. You need to start environment from scratch.